# Bash + Calculate Alarm if threshold is under the minimum

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell, awk

I created the following command in order to get the total and used memory

```
      top -n1 | grep Mem | awk '{print "TOTAL="$3" USED="$7}'
```

I need to print "memory is under 20%"

```
 echo "memory is under 20%"
```

in case **used memory** is less or equal then 20%

please advice how to calculate this with bash? or awk? or perl one liner?

Comment: just want to make sure, you want to monitor **used memory** or **free** memory?

Comment: yes , but not all the time ( per demand )  I build script that evry time I run it then the script shuld give info about memory alarm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
top -n1 | grep Mem | awk '{print "TOTAL="$3" USED="$7; per=$7/$3*100; if(per<=20) print "memory is under 20%" }'
```

will produce output

```
TOTAL=1944532k USED=176456k
memory is under 20%
```

What is does?

`per=$7/$3*100` calculates the percentage

`if(per<=20) print "memory is under 20%"` checks if the `per`, percentage is less that 20%, if yes prints the message.

OR

```
top -n1 | grep Mem | awk '{print "TOTAL="$3" USED="$7; per=int($7)/int($3)*100; if(per<=20) print "memory is under 20%" }'
```

will produce output

```
TOTAL=1944532 USED=176456
memory is under 20%
```

with string values truncated to int. See the difference with the earlier output with `k` removed from output

Comment: not good because $3 and $7 include the "k" need only number ( bdw sometimes I need to chnage the threshold for example to 30% or 40% )

Comment: works fine. if you are so much woried truncate the string using `int` function as `per=int($7)/int($3)*100` answer edite

Answer (score 1):

You can get meminfo from `/proc/meminfo`, so we can save the `top/ps/free..` output parsing/grepping. How about this:

```
awk '/^MemTotal/{t=$2}/^MemFree/{f=$2}
              END{printf "Used Mem: %.2f%\n", 100*(t-f)/t}' /proc/meminfo
```

This prints out the used mem percentage. Output like:

```
Used Mem: 84.76%
```

And this line, will output used mem info only if used percentage <=20%:

```
awk '/^MemTotal/{t=$2}/^MemFree/{f=$2}
         END{p=100*(t-f)/t; if(p<=20)printf "Used Mem<20%: %.2f%\n",p}' /proc/meminfo
```